# How to bind notation scope to a type

Tags: coq

Consider the following toy development:

```
Declare Scope entails_scope.
Bind Scope entails_scope with nat.

Reserved Notation "A |- B" (at level 60, no associativity).
Inductive entails: nat -> nat -> Prop :=
| id {A}: A |- A

where "A |- B" := (entails A B) : entails_scope.

(* Fails with message: 'Unknown interpretation for notation "_ |- _".' *)
Fail Goal exists (A B: nat), A |- B.
```

Based on Adam Chlipala's *Certified Programming with Dependent Types*, I would have expected some variant of this to parse `A |- B` as `entails A B` whenever `A` and `B` are known to be `nat`. But this doesn't happen. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to either open the newly introduce scope

```
Open Scope entails_scope.
Goal exists (A B: nat), A |- B.
```

or specify it explicitly

```
Delimit Scope entails_scope with E.
Goal exists (A B: nat), (A |- B)%E.
```

Comment: If I open the scope then it clashes with the notation for Ltac goal matching, which is what I was trying to avoid by tying this notation to a scope. The alternative would be to use Delimit Scope, but then I don't understand what the point of Bind Scope is.

Comment: FWIW, `Bind Scope entails_scope with nat.` just changes the scope of the arguments of `entails`: `Arguments entails _%entails_scope _%entails_scope`. Without `Bind Scope` it would be `Arguments entails _%nat_scope _%nat_scope`.